# Dealing with different MSSQL geometry types in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server-spatial

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 spatial database holding both point and polygon geometry data types. Displaying the data with the software which captures the data is not a problem, but ArcGIS 10.3.1 cannot display both points and polyons in a single layer.

Is there any way in which I can teach ArcGIS to display both datatypes within a single layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an absolute requirement for ArcGIS that layer sources (geometry tables or views) only contain one topology class (point/multipoint/polyline/polygon). Topology class is a fundamental property of a layer; you *cannot* convince ArcGIS to render a source where both points and polygons are returned in a single query.

There are many reasons to honor this constraint in database design, but the most pressing are performance-related: Why complicate a query by removing things that can't be rendered?  It's a waste of index overhead and block acess to remove things that won't be used together. This rule applies to rows of the same topology class as well (i.e., you shouldn't put rivers and roads in the same table for the same reason).

A decade ago I worked a customer's project where the principal goal was to place all objects in a single table to "simplify access". I told them it violated design standards and was unlikely to succeed. They were quite emphatic that they could address all the issues in implementation. They were only able to get to the first design review stage before a "stop work" order was issued and the contract terminated.

If you kluge your way around intermingled data with views or query definition constraints keyed to [STGeometryType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933825.aspx), performance *always* suffers (the *type* property is not indexable). If your table is small and never grows larger, the fundamental inefficiency may be masked, but once you reach ~50-100k features, the design limitation will start to noticeably impair function.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your input. The number of objects is unlikely to reach 10,000. The database design of the capture software does indeed permit multiple datatypes and they will be held in the same spatial database table. Can I somehow sort the geometries through an sql querylayer so i can produce an ArcGIS Layer for each geometry type?